# How to output the results of a raw SQL Active Record select query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am testing some Active Record call in the console.  I often have raw SQL selects like this:

```
Model.joins(:other_model).where(some_column:foo).select("other_model.column AS col1, model.column AS col2")
```

Which will just result this:

```
[#<Model:0x00007fa45f25b3d0 id: nil>,
 #<Model:0x00007fa45f25b1c8 id: nil>,
 #<Model:0x00007fa45f25afc0 id: nil>,
 #<Model:0x00007fa45f25acc8 id: nil>,
 #<Model:0x00007fa45f25aa48 id: nil>,
 #<Model:0x00007fa45f25a6d8 id: nil>]
```

Can I have the console output the values from the `"other_model.column"`?  I swear I saw a trick for this before but can't seem to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, the issue is that ActiveRecord is going to attempt to cast the resulting rows as `Model`s. However, the attributes are still loaded! They're just not in the string representation of the model, since they don't exist as columns on the table.

Given a relation:

```
relation = Model.joins(:other_model).where(some_column:foo)
                .select("other_model.column AS col1, model.column AS col2")
```

You can easily see the computed columns by just mapping out `#attributes`:

```
relation.map(&:attributes)
```

You will still end up with `id` fields in attributes regardless, but you can easily ignore them, or further process the mapped attributes to remove them if needed.

For example:

```
> Account.where("id < 1000")
         .select("id * 1024 as bigid")
         .limit(10)
         .map(&:attributes)
=> [{"id"=>nil, "bigid"=>819200},
    {"id"=>nil, "bigid"=>820224},
    {"id"=>nil, "bigid"=>822272}]
```

Another alternative would be to skip the ActiveRecord loading, and use `#to_sql` to just execute a raw query. In this case, I have a Postgres connection, so I'm using `#exec_query`; it may vary based on your RDBMS:

Given our relation:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(relation.to_sql).to_hash
=> [{"bigid"=>"819200"}, {"bigid"=>"820224"}, {"bigid"=>"822272"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `#pluck` method to get an array of column values, for example:

```
Model.joins(:other_model).where(some_column:foo).pluck("other_model.column")
```

Comment: That works but I edited my question to be clearer of my intent - would have multiple columns to return and view.