# Rails Upgrade to 5.2.4.1 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying an upgrade from:

- Ruby 2.2.2
- Rails 5.0.0
- Gemfile.lock

  - attr_encrypted (3.1.0)
  - encryptor (~> 3.0.0)

to

- Ruby 2.6.5
- Rails 5.2.4.1
- Gemfile.lock

  - attr_encrypted (3.1.0)
  - encryptor (~> 3.0.0)

and it's now failing in controller methods for `attr_encrypted` fields.

I have the following action:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        # make sure that only users who have Organization reading abilities see this page
        authorize! :read, Organization
      end

      if current_user.organization_resource?
        params[:organization] = current_user.organization.id
      elsif current_user.isv_resource?
        params[:isv] = current_user.isv.id
      end

      format.json do
        render json: Organization.paginated_summary(
          params[:offset].to_i,
          params[:per_page].to_i,
          query:           params[:query],
          isv_id:          params[:isv],
          organization_id: params[:organization],
          tz_cookie:       cookies[:tzOffset].blank? ? 'UTC' : cookies[:tzOffset]
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

and it's failing with `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - missing attribute: encrypted_api_token` where `api_token` is the field that is attr_encrypted and it's not being requested in that query

If I execute the block that is being rendered

```
Organization.paginated_summary(
          params[:offset].to_i,
          params[:per_page].to_i,
          query:           params[:query],
          isv_id:          params[:isv],
          organization_id: params[:organization],
          tz_cookie:       cookies[:tzOffset].blank? ? 'UTC' : cookies[:tzOffset]
        )
```

it's working and returning the expected data. Still it's failing when `render json:` the information and I am not able to track it down.

If I remove the attr_encrypted property from the field, then no error is being returned.

Has anyone encountered this type of issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of the `attr_encrypted` gem do you use? Did you update the attr_encrypted gem too? What version did you use before?

Comment: @spickermann I have updated the description; It's the same attr_encrypted version

Comment: How does the `attr_encrypted ...` line in that model look like?

Comment: `attr_encrypted :api_token, key: ENV['P2PE_KEY']`

Comment: Is there an `encrypted_api_token` column on the database table for that model?

Comment: Yes there is; there are 2 columns: `encrypted_api_token` and `encrypted_api_token_iv`

Comment: I seem to have found the issue, which in older active record was not an issue apparently. When using Organization.select('x,y,z').to_json, it's no longer working in newer version and it's trying to access all fields from that class, instead of using only the selected fields. It looks like we'll have to rewrite queries to be raw SQL for this type of situation or to use map(&:attributes) on the result. This was of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895003/how-to-output-the-results-of-a-raw-sql-active-record-select-query

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the issue, which in older active record was not an issue apparently. When using Organization.select('x,y,z').to_json, it's no longer working in newer version and it's trying to access all fields from that class, instead of using only the selected fields. It looks like we'll have to rewrite queries to be raw SQL for this type of situation or to use map(&:attributes) on the result. This was of help: [How to output the results of a raw SQL Active Record select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895003/how-to-output-the-results-of-a-raw-sql-active-record-select-query)